# Dynamically Created Form Elements not submitting with form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jsp

I have added some input type elemets in form using javascript.On submitting the form, these elements are not showing

```
var pos=document.getElementById(rid).rowIndex;
var new_row=document.getElementById("table1").insertRow(1+pos); 
new_row.id="newRow"+rowCount;
    var td5=new_row.insertCell(4);
    td5.align="left";
    td5.innerHTML="<textarea id=\"emailID\" name=\"emailID\" cols=\"40\" rows=\"5\" class=\"textbox\"></textarea>";
```

I also checked with

```
    var emailText=document.createElement("textarea");
    emailText.id='emailID';
    emailText.name='emailID',
    emailText.cols=40;
    emailText.rows=5;
    emailText.className="textbox";
    td5.appendChild(emailText);
```

On submit i checked

```
alert(document.formName.emailID);
```

But this is showing undefined.
Can any tell where i am wrong?

Comment: Try this `form.appendChild(td5);` and please verify the ID your are passing in the first line.

Comment: ID in first line is checked. Because row is inserted at proper place

Comment: Its working here. Check **[Sample Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jVXgT/1/)**

Comment: check whether the `formName` is same as the dynamically created form.

Comment: Yes when i am using document.getElementById('emailID');
It is working but not when document.formName.emailID
I have to use it on Action by request.getParameter("emailID")
and for that it has to be added in form

Comment: and form.appendChild() is working but it wont add td in tr.

Answer (score -1):

Try out like this:

```
document.forms[0].elements["emailID"];
```